# carousel slider create custom how to stop when user mouser over to carousel slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create a small carousel for javascript code is here

```
$.fn.calcslider = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        autoslide: false,
        autoslideInterval : 1000,
        slideInterval : 1000
    }, options );
    return this.each(function(){
        var autoslide = '', scope = $(this),
        liLength = scope.find('.calc-list li').length,
        liWidth = scope.find('.calc-list li').outerWidth(true),
        totalWidth = liLength * liWidth,
        flag = true;
        scope.find('.calc-list ul').width(totalWidth);

        if(liLength == 1){
           scope.find('.prev-slide').addClass('hide');
           scope.find('.next-slide').addClass('hide');
        }

        var setAutoSider = function(check){
            if(settings.autoslide){
                if(check == 'clear'){
                    clearInterval(autoslide);
                }else{
                    autoslide = setInterval(function(){
                        scope.find('.next-slide').trigger('click');
                    }, settings.autoslideInterval);
                }   
            }               
        }

        setAutoSider('set');

        scope.find('.prev-slide').stop(true, true).click(function(){
            if(flag == true){
                flag = false;
                setAutoSider('clear');
                var lastLi = scope.find('.calc-list ul li:last-child').detach();
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').prepend(lastLi);
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').css('marginLeft' , '-'+ liWidth +'px');
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').animate({
                    marginLeft : '0'
                },settings.slideInterval, function(){
                    flag = true;
                    setAutoSider('set');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
        scope.find('.next-slide').stop(true, true).click(function(){
            if(flag == true){
                flag = false;
                setAutoSider('clear');
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').animate({
                    marginLeft : '-'+ liWidth +'px'
                },settings.slideInterval, function(){
                    var firstLi = scope.find('.calc-list ul li:first-child').detach();
                    scope.find('.calc-list ul').append(firstLi);
                    scope.find('.calc-list ul').css('marginLeft' , 0);
                    flag = true;
                    setAutoSider('set');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

and i used to this

```
$('.mywrap').calcslider({
    autoslide : true,
    autoslideInterval : 5000,
    slideInterval : 500
});
```

it's working fine now now i m expend to one functinality to this 
If user mouse hover to this then it's stop working and mouse out than it's working now .

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using jQuery. You can use the jQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method to achieve this. It accepts 2 callback functions, one when you hover in and another when you hover out.

So it could be something like (within your main function):

```
scope.hover( function() {
  // this one is fired when you point on the element
  setAutoSider( 'clear' );
}, function() {
  // this one is fired when you leave the element
  setAutoSider('set');
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer for future users:

```
$.fn.calcslider = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        autoslide: false,
        autoslideInterval : 1000,
        slideInterval : 1000
    }, options );
    return this.each(function(){
        var autoslide = '', scope = $(this),
        liLength = scope.find('.calc-list li').length,
        liWidth = scope.find('.calc-list li').outerWidth(true),
        totalWidth = liLength * liWidth,
        flag = true;
        scope.find('.calc-list ul').width(totalWidth);
        
        if(liLength == 1){
           scope.find('.prev-slide').addClass('hide');
           scope.find('.next-slide').addClass('hide');
        }
        
        var setAutoSider = function(check){
            if(settings.autoslide){
                if(check == 'clear'){
                    clearInterval(autoslide);
                }else{
                    autoslide = setInterval(function(){
                        scope.find('.next-slide').trigger('click');
                    }, settings.autoslideInterval);
                }   
            }               
        }
        
        setAutoSider('set');
        scope.mouseenter(function(){
            setAutoSider('clear');    
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            setAutoSider('set');
        });
        
        scope.find('.prev-slide').stop(true, true).click(function(){
            if(flag == true){
                flag = false;
                //setAutoSider('clear');
                var lastLi = scope.find('.calc-list ul li:last-child').detach();
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').prepend(lastLi);
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').css('marginLeft' , '-'+ liWidth +'px');
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').animate({
                    marginLeft : '0'
                },settings.slideInterval, function(){
                    flag = true;
                    //setAutoSider('set');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
        scope.find('.next-slide').stop(true, true).click(function(){
            if(flag == true){
                flag = false;
                //setAutoSider('clear');
                scope.find('.calc-list ul').animate({
                    marginLeft : '-'+ liWidth +'px'
                },settings.slideInterval, function(){
                    var firstLi = scope.find('.calc-list ul li:first-child').detach();
                    scope.find('.calc-list ul').append(firstLi);
                    scope.find('.calc-list ul').css('marginLeft' , 0);
                    flag = true;
                   // setAutoSider('set');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```